# Call Method by string value from data base

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection

So I have a cell in my Oracle table, its value will be some System function or some Static Property like `DateTime.Now.Year`. 
at the table cell the type is `VARCHAR2` in `.Net` its string.

How can I produce a Generic Code for each case (Property, static Function) to get the value in the string

```
string str = "DateTime.Now.Year" // the value comes from DataBase
var valueFromDataBase = str.invoke();
```

Comment: Is it possible to store the type and the method in 2 different fields in your table ?

Comment: In the table I have only the cell with the function or the property name 
 as string, when I get this string from the database I want to call it cuz its property and get its value, but its string and this is my problem

Comment: We could eventually get what you want by using reflection but in order to do so, we must know what is a type, property, and so on... Storing them inside different columns makes that easier ! Moreover, the type must be known as their `FullName` property e.g. `System.DateTime` otherwise we must add some using statements to reference an assembly

Comment: I have the ability to modify the table, so I will split the type and column X will be property and column Y will by the full Name of one of the types. how from "System.DateTime.Now.Year" as a string I can get its value?

Comment: Do note that your proposed logic allows *everyone* who has write permissions on that table to access arbitrary .NET properties or "system function"s. That sounds really useful! [What could possibly go wrong?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log4Shell)

Answer (score 1):

Considering you're storing a type and a property

```cs
public class Entity
{
    public string TypeName { get; set; }
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
new Entity { TypeName = typeof(DateTime).FullName ; PropertyName = nameof(DateTime.Now) }
```

using reflection you can now reverse the process

```cs
public static object? GetPropertyValue(string typeName, string propertyName)
{
    var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
    var types = assemblies.SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes());
    
    var type = types.First(t => t.FullName == typeName);
    var property = type
        .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
        .First(p => p.Name == propertyName);

    return property.GetValue(null);
}
```

```cs
var datetime = GetPropertyValue(entityFromDb.TypeName, entityFromDb.PropertyName);
```

Comment: How come I didn't think of that?
Thank's a lot!